# Extract archives to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to download zip archives, extract them and load to S3. I thought about using Lambda to handle downloading and unarchiving, but it has disk size limits.

What would be the best service to do this? I can't use my local machine, because I expect the job to run for several days.

Comment: From where are you "downloading zip archives"? How big are the unzipped files? (Lambda has a limit of 500MB of temporary disk space.) When you upload to S3, are the files zipped or unzipped? How much data is there (MBs, GBs, TBs)?

Comment: Each zip archive is about 500-700 MB. I want to upload unzipped content to S3. The total size is about 40TB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that AWS Lambda is not appropriate for this task. The 500MB disk size limit will not allow you to expand the zip files.

Regardless, you'd also need to write a "management layer" to spawn the Lambda tasks, which is actually the more complex task.

The hardest part of the operation will be tracking progress to ensure that all files have been converted and uploaded, taking into account random failures that might happen along the way.

I would recommend something along these lines:

**1. Obtain a list of source files**

Somehow you'll need a **list of the source zip files** that you want to convert. This might be complicated if more files are appearing all the time (eg if it is a live system). You can always do a second run afterwards for additional files that appear.

**2. Create a Work Tracker**

You will need to **track the work** in some way so that the system knows which files have been processed and which ones are in-progress (especially if you work in parallel). While you don't state the number of input files, it would appear to be in the tens-of-thousands.

A very reliable method would be to create an **Amazon SQS message for each file to be processed**. Then the workers would pull from this queue (see next step). Alternatively, **use a simple database** to store the information.

**3. Do the work**

The simplest method would be to launch an Amazon EC2 instance with a script that:

- Determines the next file to process (by pulling a message from SQS or consulting a database)
- Does the work (download, unzip, upload)
- Marks the work as done (or marks it as an error, to be re-tried in a separate pass later)

Start with a small list of files to confirm that the process is working okay, then ramp-up the quantity.

To fully-utilize the bandwidth and CPU, you could **run multiple processes** on the instance. Each would operate as an independent worker.

Use **Amazon EC2 Spot Instances** to lower the cost of processing. Try a variety of instance types to find the best combination -- some have **Instance Store** that provides very fast local storage (especially those with SSD). Having some form of **logging** will help you track progress and determine which instance types seem to be performing the best, and the optimal number of parallel processes to run on each worker.

By tracking the work in SQS or a database, the process can be stopped/started without losing progress. It can also be scaled across multiple instances with multiple workers per instance.

**4. Handle the errors**

Problems will occur (bad zip files, networking glitches, random errors) so you'll want to do a second pass to try them again and investigate specific errors. Your system needs to keep track of such problems so they can be re-processed.

**5. Audit the results**

Assuming that you want *all* the files processed, you should do a final pass where you compare the list of source files against the final list of uploaded files.

The method would depend upon how you are uploading the files to S3 -- this job would be a lot easier if S3 objects are named based upon their source (eg a source file of `A01.zip` would be expanded to `A01/file1`, `A01/file2`, etc).

**Bottom line:** The work you are doing is quite simple. Tracking the work will take more effort than actually doing the work.

Comment: Additional: [AWS Batch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) might also be good for this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is : get a EC2 nano instance ( very very cheap ).. attach EBS volume.. write a small bash script which downloads file using wget/curl and the upload to S3 using AWS CLI